# print shows output in Windows version but not Raspberry pi

Tags: python-2.7

I have the following simple function to print a message and counting down in seconds:

```
def setDelay(Duration=5, Message='Waiting'):
   while Duration>0:
     time.sleep(1)
     Duration -= 1
     print "%s... %i   \r" % (Message,Duration),
   print " "*(len(Message)+10)  #clears the line
```

This has been working fine for years in Python 2.7 in Windows. I just tried this out on Python in a Raspberry Pi, the delay is there but nothing is shown on the screen.

How should I fix it?

Comment: Which version of Python is running on your Raspberry Pi?

Comment: 2.7.3 (default, Mar 18 2014, 05:13:23)
[GCC 4.6.3]

Comment: either skip last `,` in print call or add `\n` at the end of printed string to force stdout flush.

Comment: I have `\r` as the last character on the line and a trailing `,`  so that the line will overwrite itself as the seconds count down.  Is there a way to ask it not to buffer?